# Is there any reason not to use yaml anchors consistently for selectors in Deployments, and similar use cases

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

It has always bugged me (in the few months so far I've been using) in Kubernetes that the labels for a pod template (or similar) has to be cut-pasted/kept consistent with the selector, say in a `Deployment`.  It MAY be that there are use cases for deployments doing fancier things, but I don't really see those.  It also is confusing since most examples have the same labels on the deployment and pod template, which obscures what the selector is doing.

Does anyone have any downsides or reasons to AVOID this pattern.  Or explain use-cases where the selector and pod labels would reasonably diverge (which still doesn't justify avoiding this for the common use case).

This works (at least with the YAML parser in current k8s), gets rid of the duplication, and seems clear to me.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deploy-nginx
  labels:
     app: nginxOrNot
     stage: prod
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: &podLabels
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: deploy-container
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
  selector:
    matchLabels: *podLabels
```

It does require you put the selector after the template but it makes clear to me what the selector is selecting.  If desired you could put the anchor on the deployment label, and reference it on the pod template and selector, if you want them all to always be the same... I don't think its relevant that Helm could reduce the duplication - for a given helm template, this approach is still reasonable.

Comment: A little bit, I'm not clear on why this isn't the default behavior (like allowing selector to be omitted) for Kubernetes even IF there are use cases for selectors in Deployments, ReplicaSet, ... that do something different.

Comment: Oh, and [this doc about YAML anchors](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/yaml-anchors-aliases-overrides-extensions/#yaml-anchors-and-aliases) mentions why using anchors is useful by making clear what parts are the same and reducing maintenance.